# Error when using Unicode MySQL ODBC driver in R

Tags: r, odbc, mysql-connector, dbi

I'm having difficulty connecting to a remote MySQL server from my Mac using the Unicode MySQL ODBC driver. The error message is unhelpful:

```r
library(DBI)
library(odbc)

dbConnect(
  drv = odbc(),
  driver = "/usr/local/mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.23-macos10.15-x86-64bit/lib/libmyodbc8w.so",
  server = "server.address",
  user = Sys.getenv("DATABASE_USERNAME"),
  password = Sys.getenv("DATABASE_PASSWORD"),
  port = 3306
)
#> Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

But if I run the same code using the Ansi driver I can connect successfully:

```r
library(DBI)
library(odbc)

dbConnect(
  drv = odbc(),
  driver = "/usr/local/mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.23-macos10.15-x86-64bit/lib/libmyodbc8a.so",
  server = "server.address",
  user = Sys.getenv("DATABASE_USERNAME"),
  password = Sys.getenv("DATABASE_PASSWORD"),
  port = 3306
)
#> <OdbcConnection> user@server.address via TCP/IP
#>   Database: null
#>   MySQL Version: 8.0.20
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

What steps can I take to debug?

Comment: Side note, that error message (`"["`) looks like it should be a bug report to either [`odbc`](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues) or [`nanodbc`](https://github.com/nanodbc/nanodbc/issues/) (or both).

Comment: Another side note, you do not need to specify full path of .so but its driver name especially if you intend to distribute code. Check in config file: `ODBCINST.INI` file. See [Setting up ODBC Drivers](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/drivers/).

Comment: I’m aware of that. Thank you!

Comment: The same issue continued with RStudio, as well. Cannot add ODBC connection for both ANSI or Unicode drivers..